# Does $x_{k}=(-1)^{k}(1-\frac{1}{k+1})$ converge to $-1$ in $X=[-1, 0) \cup (0, 1)$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

in R, $x_k$ does not converge to $-1$.

$X=[-1, 0) \cup (0, 1)$

then, in X, Does $x_k$ converge to $-1$?

My textbook says :

A sequence $x_k$ in X converges in X if there exists a point $x_0$ in X such that $\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty}x_{k}=x_{0}$.

I'm confused, so help me.

Comment: $|x_k-(-1)|=2-\frac 1 {k+1} \to 2$ as $ k \to \infty$ through even integers.

Comment: but I think $x_k$ has only 1 cluster point in X and bounded, so $x_k$ converges in X. Is this wrong? If wrong, then why?

Comment: In a compact metric space a seqeuence with a unique cluster point converges. That is not true in a general metric space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not converge to $-1$.  In order to converge to $-1$, the sequence would have to eventually *always* be arbitrarily close to $-1$.  This sequence oscillates between being close to $-1$ and far from $-1$.

However, $-1$ is the only accumulation point in $X = [-1, 0) \cup (0, 1)$.  It just doesn't converge to $-1$.